# How to keep given password in mgtwitterengine api

Tags: iphone, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I want to keep password which is given by user in a variable. Where to get password value. I look in code but it is containing only username. I am using MGTwitterengine api in my application. Here is the function which is printing data on console.

```
-(void)setUsername:(NSString *)newUsername password:(NSString *)newPassword
{
     NSLog(@"uset sername %@ and password %@",newUsername,newPassword);
     ...
}
```

I debug in all function but I saw this function is running after loggedin. But this is printing null in password value although username is printing well. Actually I I have to trace all tweet value of user. I went through MGTwitterEngine. There is a block of code but it is necessary to write username and password.

Here is the code

```
MGTwitterEngine *twitterEngine = [[MGTwitterEngine alloc] initWithDelegate:self]; 

[twitterEngine setUsername:@"username" password:@"password"]; 
// Get updates from people the authenticated user follows. 

NSString *connectionID = [twitterEngine getFollowedTimelineFor:nil since:nil startingAtPage:0];
```

Please help me how to keep password ?

Comment: I don't understand your question, are you asking how can you "save" the password of the user? Also if you are targeting iOS5 for your release consider using TwitterKit

Comment: @Devraj Apple's KGB devision shoots developers that mention the top secret "T" word. ;) NDA is still active!

Comment: @DavidSchiefer Oops, I watched the Keynote and there was mention of it, so I thought its knowledge was public but not how it works. Either ways sorry Apple! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action), it provides all the info you need for something as easy as this. Back to the question, there're a couple of ways how you can save this data.

**NSUserDefaults**: You can save the `username` and `password` using this class like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults sharedUserDefaults] setObject:username forKey:@"username"];
[[NSUserDefaults sharedUserDefaults] setObject:username forKey:@"password"];
[[NSUserDefaults sharedUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Once you need this data again, call it:

```
NSString*username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"];
NSString*password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"password"];
```

**OR:**

**NSDictionary**: If you don't want to rely on `NSUserDefaults`, you can save the login data in a `NSDictionary` and save it to your sandbox. This works like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary*loginDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[loginDictionary setObject:username forKey:@"username"];
[loginDictionary setObject:password forKey:@"password"];
[loginDictionary writeToFile://Your Path Here atomically:NO];

[loginDictionary release];
```

Then, once you need the data again, read from file:

```
NSMutableDictionary*loginDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile://Your Path];

NSString*username = [loginDictionary objectForKey:@"username"];
NSString*password = [loginDictionary objectForKey:@"password"];

[loginDictionary release];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I believe that sfhfkeychainutils is more secure than NSUserDefaults, if you need to store passwords

Comment: Very fair point, but I felt that this user needed an answer that beginners could understand too. I myself would use NSDictionary and encrypt it with AES.